# Django 'str' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error for below two line:

```
subscriber.email.add(self.cleaned_data.get('email'))
subscriber.address.add(self.cleaned_data.get('address'))
```

I am using AbstractUser model and trying to add extra fields by adding new model class. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Subscriber(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(UserManagement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=100) 
      address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**froms.py**

```
class SubscriberSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
      email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
      address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

      class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
           model = UserManagement
      

      @transaction.atomic
      def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_subscriber = True
        user.save()
        subscriber= Subscriber.objects.create(user=user)
        subscriber.email.add(self.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        subscriber.address.add(self.cleaned_data.get('address'))
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
class SubscriberSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = UserManagement
    form_class = SubscriberSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'subscriber'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('blog:my-account')
```

console error:

```
 File "P:\django\django\farhyn\members\forms.py", line 21, in save
    subscriber.email.add(self.cleaned_data.get('email'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add'
[27/Jul/2021 08:29:31] "POST /subscriber-signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99927
```

Comment: @Klaus D. Thanks for your comment. Can you please  tell me then  how I can add others strings fields like address????how to use add() in email ???

Comment: @KlausD. can or can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`email` and `address` are string fields, and in Python there is no `add(...)` method for `str` objects.

Most probably, you are looking for something like this,

```
class SubscriberSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = UserManagement

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_subscriber = True
        user.save()
        Subscriber.objects.create(
            user=user,
            email=self.cleaned_data.get('email'),
            address=self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        )
        return user
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use add on email since it's a string. This might work:

```
subscriber.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
subscriber.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
```

Comment: didn't saw the comment what others people say...they already said I can't add it.

Comment: @boyenec Mauricio didn't tell you to do anything wrong here bro... Look at what he wrote, he didn't mentioned `add` in his code. He is explicitly setting the fields on the subscriber object. But if you are to have `subscriber.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')` and `subscriber.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')` you will have to call the save method on the subscriber object `subscriber.save()`.

Comment: So this makes JPG's answer more efficient even though Mauricio's method plus `subscriber.save()` does the same.

Comment: He  posted the duplicate answers which solution alardady given above

Comment: Sorry but we were just about 15 to 30 seconds away. I dion't read the other answer but it was the first posted. I wouldn't penalize any one for that.